# Separating index values from an array inside discord embed

Tags: discord.py, replit

I'm looking for a way to spit out an embed that lists all the "suggestions" in my database with their corresponding index values [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWhom.png) So far I can send an embed with all of the information [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z1kt.png) but that just adds the information as 2 strings after each other (suggestions then the index values).

I need a way to display the "suggestions" in the embed with the index values separately like this:

```
[#1] suggestion 1
[#2] suggestion 2
[#3] suggestion 3
[#4] suggestion 4
```

Ideally this would all be done within one embed field.

I'm sorry if this was poorly worded but if I knew how to describe what I'm looking for, I might have found the answer sooner. Thanks for any advice in advance.

(I'm using the replit database - if any more of the code is needed please let me know)

```py
@client.command()
async def suggestions(ctx):
  suggestions = []
  if "suggestions" in db.keys():
    suggestions = db["suggestions"]
  joined = '\n'.join([str(elem) for elem in suggestions])
  index_number = '\n'.join([str(i) for i in range(len(suggestions))])
  channel = client.get_channel(0000000000000)
  
  suggestionsEmbed=discord.Embed(title="Server Suggestions", description="Vote for suggestions with **$vote #** Remove suggestions with **$del #**", color=0x15e538)
  suggestionsEmbed.set_thumbnail(url="https://www.startup.pk/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/ideaideabulblightbulbicon-1320144733751939202.png")  
  suggestionsEmbed.add_field(name='Suggestions Created', value=f'{joined} **#{index_number}**')

  await channel.send(embed=suggestionsEmbed)
```

Comment: You could use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function.

Comment: @Sandy fantastic idea. Ill try that now thanks!